# Вывод в таблицу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть форма, в которую ввожу ид.

```
        <form onsubmit="return false" action="" method="GET">
            <fieldset class="intrigue">
                <legend>
                    <h3>Укажите steamID</h3>
                </legend>
                <input placeholder='Введите steamID' id="SteamId" name="SteamId" type="text" value="">
                <input placeholder='Отправить' type='submit'>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Затем ajax, который посылает на сервер запрос(ссылка + ид).

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {

    var UserId = $('input[name=SteamId]').val();
    if (UserId.length > 0) {
        alert('Всё норм!');
        SubmitForm(UserId);
    } else {
        alert("Вы забыли указать имя");
    }
});

function SubmitForm(UserId) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://project-megaroks931128.codeanyapp.com/users/add/?usersid=" + UserId,
        dataType: "jsonp";
    })
}
```

Приходит массив данных в json

```
{
    "steamid": "76561198049827777",
    "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
    "profilestate": 1,
    "personaname": "tlmcmerty",
    "lastlogoff": 1503799076,
    "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198049827777/",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg",
    "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg",
    "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg",
    "personastate": 0,
    "realname": "joshua tree",
    "primaryclanid": "103582791429521408",
    "timecreated": 1317492330,
    "personastateflags": 0,
```

Как мне вывести в мою таблицу содержимою таблицу например поле steamid?

```
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>SteamID</th>
         <td>Что сюда писать?</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: _"все смешалось в доме Облонских"_ ©

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко, то добавить к ячейке идентификатор а-ля

```
 <td id="steam-id">Что сюда писать?</td>
```

а ajax-вызов  замените на что-то вроде

```
$.getJSON("http://project-megaroks931128.codeanyapp.com/users/add/?usersid=" + UserId,
          function(data){
             console.log(data.steamid);
             $("td#steam-id").text(data.steamid);
          }
    });
```

либо подобный обратный вызов прикрутить к исходному `$.ajax`-запросу.

*А вообще, заметьте, что посути вам вообще не нужна `<form>` в принципе, еще и с перекрытием `onsubmit` ибо данные вы отправляете все равно аяксом независимо от формы. `input` поле можно разместит и вне формы.

А в результирующей таблице у вас странным образом соседствуют `th` и `td`.*

---

Итого, у вас должен быть инпут для ввода, кнопка для отправки, и еще поле для вставки значения.

```
<input type="text" id="steamId"/>
<a href="#" id="check">Отправить</a>
<span id="steam-id-result"></span>
```

а также код наподобие следующего

```
$("#check").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var sid = $("#steamId").val().trim();
     if(!sid){
         alert(....);
         return;
     }
     $.getJSON("...", function(data){
         $("#steam-id-result").text(data.steamid);
     });
});
```

Comment: у меня такая проблема что даже console.log(JSON.parse(data.steamid)); не выводит в консоль

Comment: ответ то приходит вообще? функция сам по себе выполнется? поставьте там точку остановка да посмотрите что на входе.

Comment: Вот вкладке network отображаются данные, что я указывал в теме выше

Comment: те же самые что и по ссылке http://project-megaroks931128.codeanyapp.com/users/add/?usersid=76561198049827777

Comment: а json.parse вы зачем вызываете при выводе в консоль?

Comment: я убирал его, все равно в консоль ничего не приходит

Comment: дак вы можете отладчиком воспользоваться-то  или нет?